# How can I host my API for android mobile app

Tags: android, rest

My team planning to create an android app and currently we are still in the planning stage. I have a question, do we need to purchase an API hosting? Currently we already have VPS hosting
where we use to host the web based version of our system. Can we just use our VPS or need to buy a new one?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VPS hosting you have now to provide the API.

However, since it requires tasks such as user creation, permission management, and package management within the hosting, if the cost is not high, it is recommended to purchase and use a new hosting.

Comment: may I know what you mean with permission management and package management? if I want to purchase another hosting to host the API, what type of hosting is the best for me to choose?

Comment: It depends on framework you using for API service, expected traffic, ..etc.